# Hiding (not eliminating) duplicates in ColdFusion array

Tags: coldfusion

We have a three-panel display in which Panel One shows a list of countries, Panel Two shows a list of organizations, and Panel Three shows a list of aircraft. If you click a country, both the organizations and aircraft are filtered by that country, using IDs for each.

This is all working fine, but the list of aircraft comes from a "linking table" -- each record contains aircraft ID and name, and operator ID and name. Any given type of aircraft can be listed multiple times, depending on how many organizations operate it. For example, "AW159 Wildcat" is listed twice, once for Army Air Corps and once for Royal Navy. The way it works right now, "AW159" is listed in Panel Three twice when the page initially loads.

I would like any given aircraft to be displayed only once on initial page load, regardless of how many times it may be listed in this linking table. But, I want all the "duplicates" available to be shown, if somebody filters on the operating organization.

Is there a way to loop over all the aircraft but somehow hide duplicates of aircraft ID? Or, might there be a larger problem with the way our database is designed? I am open to suggestions. Thank you all very much in advance!

EDIT: sorry for not posting code; here is some. Thanks everybody for all of your help!

**1. Query and array population in cfc:**

```
    <cfquery name="queryByOperator" datasource="vertipedia">
        SELECT view_aircraftbyoperators.aircraftID
          , view_aircraftbyoperators.Aircraft
          , view_aircraftbyoperators.operatorID
          , view_aircraftbyoperators.Operator
          , tbl_companies.country 
          , tbl_companies.companyShortName
        FROM view_aircraftbyoperators JOIN tbl_companies 
            ON tbl_companies.ID = view_aircraftbyoperators.operatorID
        ORDER BY Aircraft
    </cfquery>

    <cfset count = 1>
    <cfset aircraftByOperator = arrayNew(2)>

    <cfloop query="queryByOperator">
        <cfset aircraftByOperator[count][1] = aircraftID>
        <cfset aircraftByOperator[count][2] = Aircraft>
        <cfset aircraftByOperator[count][3] = operatorID>
        <cfset aircraftByOperator[count][4] = Operator>
        <cfset aircraftByOperator[count][5] = country>
        <cfset count = count+1>
    </cfloop>
```

**2. Outputting on page:**

```
<ul>
<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(aircraftByOperator)#" index="i">
    <cfoutput>
    <li name="#aircraftByOperator[i][3]#" class="#aircraftByOperator[i][5]#">
    <p>
        <a href="aircraft.cfm?aircraftID=#aircraftByOperator[i][1]#">#aircraftByOperator[i][2]#</a>
    </p>
    </li>
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
</ul>
```

[i][1], [i][3] and [i][5] are all IDs. "operatorID" is the one that will change depending on who operates the aircraft. I hope this helps explain what I am trying, and again, many thanks!

Comment: Maybe a Q of Q that starts with "select distinct" would be ok for the initial display.

Comment: what version of CF you are using? CF9 onwards has ArrayFind function which you an use. Create an empty array before you start displaying aeroplanes, find its ID in arrayVar, if it is not there, display it as well as add it to arrayVar with arrayAppend function.

Comment: If you are on lower version, you can use LIST functions.

Comment: Please provide a code snippet to show how you're currently rendering this.  While there are plenty of suggestions that could be made, it's infinitely easier to provide a suggestion that fits in well with what you have already done.

Comment: Hello Simon, I added some code that shows how we are getting the data and outputting it on the page. Thanks for tip -- sorry I did not think to do so earlier!

Comment: Also can you provide an example of what you mean by: *...I want all the "duplicates" available to be shown. if somebody filters on the operating organization.* I do not see anything in the code that mentions organization. How is this "filtering" applied? Side note, is there a specific reason you are converting the query into an array instead of just using it "as is"?

Comment: If you want to work with arrays, cflib.org has an array distinct function available.

Comment: Hi Leigh, sorry, in this context "organization" and "operator" are interchangeable. So, the query above might return several instances of the same type of aircraft, but which is operated by many organizations. As in, "Bell UH-1, Bell UH-1, Boeing AH-64, AW-101, Bell UH-1." Where the Bell UH-1 is operated by three different organizations. In the initial display of the menu, I only want Bell UH-1 to be listed a single time. BUT, each instance returned from the query has a different Operator ID associated with it, so I'd like each one to be "available" some how, even if not initially shown.

Comment: Oh, and the filtering is done through jQuery - clicking an organization will show only those aircraft having an Operator ID that matches whatever operator was clicked. And no, no particular reason to return an array; I am just used to using array notation in loops. I hope this helps explain things!

Comment: Does this mean you are pre-loading all your data into javascript?  It might be more efficient to throw some ajax in there and just get what you need when you need it.

Comment: Yep, that is what I was wondering. daltec - There are two ways to load data: 1) Load on demand by making an ajax call and do the filtering in your query. 2) Load everything up front, then filter after the fact using javascript. How much data are you talking about? If it is a lot, option #1 is probably more efficient.

Comment: Hi Dan and Leigh, we are getting all of our data upfront and then filtering with javascript. For now, it is not much data, and we want the page to be as fast as possible. That being said, the amount of data is expected to grow substantially over the next year or so. So you are both recommending an ajax-based "on demand" approach to getting the data, correct?

Comment: That's what I recommend.  The first few times I tried it I was amazed at how fast it was.

Comment: Following up on old question! We used a "semi-ajax" route. A default set of aircraft is loaded at first, but when a visitor filters on country and/or organization, we re-query via ajax. I was having trouble formatting the returned data, so I used jQuery load() to add the HTML to the existing div in the third panel. Cheating, maybe, but it works and is pretty fast too! Dan Bracuk, I want to mark your comment as an answer, and upvote Leigh's, but I do not see those options. Maybe too much time has passed! But in any case, THANK YOU both for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Dan Bracuk's comment "Does this mean you are pre-loading all your data into javascript? It might be more efficient to throw some ajax in there and just get what you need when you need it" ended up being the way to go for us. I would like to mark his comment as the answer, but am unable to see how to do that.

For others who may read this post, we

1. Loaded all of the aircraft initially
2. When a visitor filters by country and/or organization, a new query is sent via ajax
3. I was having a hard time formatting the returned data, so I used jQuery's load() to format it and drop it in the proper place in the output panel.

As Dan said, it is very fast and much easier to work with, especially as our database continues to grow.

Thanks Dan!